# How to merge multiple rows into the single row by specific columns in R

Tags: r

I'm working with a big data(657273*7) which have many-to-many relationships. What is the most efficient way to transform this data to ensure that the x,y,cell_id column is unique and that all of the corresponding units are combined into a single row? (x is longitude, y is latidue)

```
       x        y      cell_id   population ouput0 output1 output3 output4 
1 -2.123045 53.57619   -69542       12        0       1       0       0
2 -2.123045 53.57619   -69542       12        0       0       0       1
3 -2.123045 53.57619   -69542       12        1       0       0       0
4 -2.123045 53.57619   -69542       12        0       1       2       1
5 -2.223495 54.57312   -80123       12        2       3       4       5
6 -2.223495 54.57312   -80123       12        0       0       0       1
7 -2.443454 53.43132    50123       22        1       2       3       4
...
```

into this:

```
       x        y      cell_id   population ouput0 output1 output2 output3 output4 output5 output6 output7 output8 output9 output10 output11 output12 output13 output14 output15......
1 -2.123045 53.57619   -69542       12        0       1       0       0       0       0       0       1       1       0       0        0        0        1        2        1     
2 -2.223495 54.57312   -80123       12        2       3       4       5       0       0       0       1       0       0       0        0        0        0        0        0 
3 -2.443454 53.43132    50123       22        1       2       3       4       0       0       0       0       0       0       0        0        0        0        0        0
```

The x, y, and cell_id of each column are the same, and cell_id can be used to judge. The same is merged into one column. The only change is output, from output0 to output999. If there is a value, put it in, and put it in 0 if there is no value.

Input:

```
structure(list(x = c(-2.1230448, -2.1230448, -2.1230448, -2.1230448
), y = c(53.5761851, 53.5761851, 53.5761851, 53.5761851), cell_id = c(-9222886088671299584, 
-9222886088671299584, -9222886088671299584, -9222886088671299584
), population = c(12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), infected_DM_0 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), infected_DM_1 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), infected_DM_2 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L), infected_DM_3 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(34187L, 
115706L, 168776L, 656039L), class = "data.frame")
```

Output:

```
structure(list(x = -2.1230448, y = 53.5761851, cell_id = -9222886088671299584, 
    population = 12, infected_DM_0 = 0, infected_DM_1 = 1, infected_DM_2 = 0, 
    infected_DM_3 = 0, infected_DM_4 = 0, infected_DM_5 = 0, 
    infected_DM_6 = 0, infected_DM_7 = 1, infected_DM_8 = 0, 
    infected_DM_9 = 0, infected_DM_10 = 1, infected_DM_11 = 0, 
    infected_DM_12 = 0, infected_DM_13 = 0, infected_DM_14 = 1, 
    infected_DM_15 = 0), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It will be easier to help if you can share the data in a way that will be easier for others to load. Can you please include the output of `dput(head(YOUR_TABLE, 10))` in the body of your question?

Comment: Because the data is relatively large, it is difficult to manually record the output, and only the first four lines can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using `tidyverse` (`dplyr` + `tidyr` in this case)

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("infected")) %>%
  group_by(x, y, cell_id, population) %>%
  mutate(name = paste0("output", row_number())) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value, values_fill = 0)
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 20
# Groups:   x, y, cell_id, population [1]
      x     y  cell_id population output1 output2 output3 output4 output5 output6 output7 output8 output9 output10 output11 output12 output13 output14 output15 output16
  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>      <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>
1 -2.12  53.6 -9.22e18         12       0       1       0       0       0       0       0       1       0        0        1        0        0        0        1        0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I use this approach to process my data, and the output result is what I want. And I have a question, which of the above statements can make the filled output 1000. I am new to the R language and have not used the tidyr package. I used loops and traversals to process my data in R. I ran for about 3 hours and haven’t finished it yet. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please say more about "which of the above statements can make the filled output 1000," I don't understand.